# can I using integer in verilog code to make chip

Tags: verilog

I am writing verilog code to accomplish matrix multiply.

but ways I found always using integer and for loop to accomplish.

while my professor told me that he not sure whether if there are integer declared in verilog could make into chips means send to the TSMC to create the IC.

is integer declaration only using in FPGA or it can also use in IC?

thanks.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question: Instead of asking strangers on the internet which subsets of verilog some 3rd party chip manufactoring company will accept ... simply study their specifications. I am 100% sure that any company that takes your verilog input in order to turn that into chips has very precise specifications that tell you what you can / should / should not do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this community doesn't define the interfaces that some 3rd party service is relying on.

Comment: You are welcome. And if you dare, go ask your professor why he couldn't tell you that. Seriously, when your instructor wants you to get verilog input ready to create a real chip, shouldn't he know everything about the whole process?!

Comment: @GhostCat The chip manufacturer typically takes GDS and doesn't care whether you used verilog, VHDL, hand-layout, etc. Their spec is based on layers and geometry. It's the EDA tool vendor/software that OP needs to worry about, and digging through TSMC's arcane and lengthy design rules isn't a good use of the OP's time for resolving this question.

Answer (score 1):

If the tools used on the project support Verilog, then integer variables are available.

The Verilog specification IEEE 1394 -2005 section 4.8 defines the use of integer variables in Verilog.

A quote from that section:
"An integer is a general-purpose variable used for manipulating quantities that are not regarded as hardware registers"

A snip from that section:

[image]

Here is an example of integer use in Verilog:

```
module tb ();
  
  integer a;
  integer b;
  integer c;
  
  initial 
    begin
      a = 1;
      b = 2;
      c = a + b;
      $strobe ("c = %0d",c);
    end
      
endmodule
```

Running this simulation produces:

```
xcelium> run
c = 3
```

Comment: I see, but one extra question, how to implement integer by mos? how does it looks like

Comment: I don't understand this question 'how to implement integer by mos?'  What is mos?

Comment: I mean, what does integer made by. I know register is made by latches, but how integer.

Comment: Verilog is a high level language.  The particular tool chain used to process the Verilog determines the FPGA or ASIC library component details and usage.

Comment: @SteveDeltora You're asking the wrong question - is your `integer` purely combinational, or stored in an actual clocked register? Even a `reg` can be nothing more than wires connected to combinational logic, if you're assigning to it from an `always @(*)` rather than `always @ (posedge ...)` block.